# Why is the SiteCollection Always null?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-deployment

I have the function:

```
    public SPList CreateList(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties, Dictionary<string, List<AddParams>> columns, 
        string name, string description, SPListTemplateType type, string viewDescription)
    {

        SPList spList = null;

        SPSite siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
        if (siteCollection != null)
        {
            SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb;
            web.Lists.Add(name, description, type);
            web.Update();

            // Add the new list and the new content.
            spList = web.Lists[name];
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<AddParams>> col in columns){
                spList.Fields.Add(col.Key, col.Value[0].type, col.Value[0].required);
            }

            spList.Update();

            //Create the view? - Possibly remove me.
            System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection stringCollection =
                new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<AddParams>> col in columns)
            {
                stringCollection.Add(col.Key);
            }

            //Add the list.
            spList.Views.Add(viewDescription, stringCollection, @"", 100,
                true, true, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Html, false);
            spList.Update();

            return spList;
        }

        return spList;
    }
```

Yet for some reason when debugging the siteCollection is coming back null which is causing it to not do what I want it to. When I inspect `properties.Feature.Parent` I see the site Name:  'Team Site'

So why is this null?

**Update:**

This project, is **site** scoped

Comment: It could be useful to add information on who and from what kind of application calls this method...

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons that `siteCollection` might be `null` after the line instantiating it runs:

1. `properties.Feature.Parent` is `null`
2. `properties.Feature.Parent` is not an `SPSite` (or derived from `SPSite`)

If you're saying that you can see in the debugger that `properties.Feature.Parent` is not `null` when `siteCollection` is, that means that `properties.Feature.Parent` is not an `SPSite` instance.

You can see the type of this property when debugging by opening a Watch window and entering the expression `properties.Feature.Parent.GetType()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not a kind of SPSite?  So when you cast it as something it's not it becomes null?

Comment: I have other methods very simmilar to to this that are doing the same thing, accept they are not returning null.

Comment: Why don't you check with "if (!properties.Feature.Parent is SPSite) System.Console.Write("Oh, that's why it's null!");"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `properties.Feature.Parent` is not an SPSite object.
The code `as SPSite` will set `siteCollection` to `Null` if it's an SPWeb object

Comment: is there a way to test this? when inspecting? will it tell me its type?

Comment: Yes:  properties.Feature.Parent.GetType()

Comment: I suppose you are calling this method from an event receiver that may be either Web or Site scoped? If that's the case you may want to pass in the SPWeb object explicitly

Comment: Can you see the type of properties.Feature.Parent in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to debug this, after this line `SPSite siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;`, if you run this in either your watch window or immediate window `properties.Feature.Parent.GetType()` you should be able to identify the type of object it's returning, note that it has to be a compatible type (to SPSite) to be able to cast otherwise you get the null object.